# Azure Devops: branch policies reviewer approval

Tags: azure, azure-devops, branch, policy, review

In the next scenario, I want to find the appropriate branch policy:

Before examining a PR, a reviewer (not the PR owner) would like to make sure the branch is rebased over the master branch and run it to make sure it passes.

Upon pushing the branch, the reviewer cannot approve it because:

`at least 1 reviewer besides most recent pusher must approve the most recent iteration azure devops`

Despite the fact that the branch policies are:

[master branch policy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YEK1F.png)

We would like to keep `Allow requestors to approve their own changes` unticked

Answer (score 2):

With your branch policy shared in the screenshot, you will received the warning below when another new commit or push is made upon this uncompleted but already-approved Pull Request. We suggest that you could look into the new commit or push for re-validation.

[image]

This scenario is a default system-setting. If the reviewer’s vote is already set as approved, then clicking Approve again will do nothing, because the state of the vote will not change.

Therefore, in this case, we have several workarounds for you.

1.The reviewer can reset his vote and click approve again.

2.Or a reviewer who has not voted yet can approve the request. This is an expected behavior.

3.Or you could tick the option below instead.
[image]

Besides, it’s also suggested that you could start a feature request in Developer Community for more information.
https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/report?space=21&entry=suggestion

Comment: @HodBadihi what's the latest progress